# How to put value between two tag in xml request using nusoap?

Tags: php

```
$param=array('EVRN_UnitResRQ',
'Customer'=>array('PersonName'=>array('GivenName'=>'Ryan','Surname'=>'Trayers'),'Telephone'=>array('PhoneTechType'=>'1','CountryAccessCode'=>'1','AreaCityCode'=>'206','PhoneNumber'=>'8320246'),'Email'=>array('DefaultInd'=>true),)))) )),
```

This is my sample array in this i want to put or assign value of email like `<email>example@test.com</email>`, How can i assign that. i am using nusoap web service i pass array as argument in soap client.

Answer (score 0):

```
$param=array(
 'EVRN_UnitResRQ', 
 'Customer'=>array(
 'PersonName'=> array('GivenName'=>'Ryan','Surname'=>'Trayers'),
 'Telephone'=>array(
   'PhoneTechType'=>'1',
   'CountryAccessCode'=>'1',
   'AreaCityCode'=>'206',
   'PhoneNumber'=>'8320246'),
 'Email'=>array('DefaultInd'=>true),)))))),
```

assigment:
`$param['Email'] ='test@example.com';`

Comment: but when i am assign directly than nusoap gives me "Error: wsdl error: phpType is struct, but value is not an array: see debug output for details"